# Question source - Fomatting

Tags: formatting

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage[lmargin=0.75in,rmargin=0.75in,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
 \everymath{\displaystyle} % ------------------- % Packages %
------------------- \usepackage{    amsmath,            % Math Environments     amssymb,            % Extended Symbols  enumerate,          % Enumerate
 Environments   graphicx,           % Include Images    lastpage,           % Reference
 Lastpage   multicol,           % Use Multi-columns     multirow            % Use Multi-rows
 } \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} \usepackage{tikz, tabularx}
 \usepackage{graphics}
 \newcolumntype{W}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%Para agilizar las
 columnas. % ------------------- % Font % -------------------
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{charter}

 
 % ------------------- % Commands % -------------------
 \newcommand{\homework}[2]{\noindent\textbf{Nombre completo:
 }\makebox[3in]{\hrulefill} \hfill \textbf{IQ 0312} \\  \textbf{Fecha
 de entrega: #2} \hfill \textbf{Simulacro #1}\\}
 
 \newcommand{\prob}{\noindent\textbf{Problema. }} \newcounter{problema}
 \newcommand{\problem}{     \stepcounter{problema}%     \noindent
 \textbf{Problema \theproblem. }% } \newcommand{\pointproblem}[1]{
    \stepcounter{problema}%     \noindent \textbf{Problema \theproblem.} (#1
 points)\,% } \newcommand{\pspace}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}
 \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

 
 % ------------------- % Theorem Environment % -------------------
 \mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%    frametitlerule=true,
    roundcorner=5pt,    linecolor=black,    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    middlelinewidth=0.5pt }
 \mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{exercise}{\textbf{Problema}}


 
 % ------------------- % Header & Footer % -------------------
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
 \fancypagestyle{pages}{    %Headers    \fancyhead[L]{}     \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %Footers
    \fancyfoot[L]{}     \fancyfoot[C]{}     \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \,de
 \pageref{LastPage}} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt} }
 \headheight=0pt \footskip=14pt
 
 \pagestyle{pages}
 
 % ------------------- % Content % ------------------- \begin{document}
 \homework{\#}{MM/DD}

 
 % Question 1 \begin{exercise}\textit{JEE (Advanced)}: Mostre que
 $$\frac{\cot x-1}{\cot x+1}=\frac{\cos{(2x)}}{1+\sin{(2x)}}$$  
 \end{exercise}


 
 % Question 2 \begin{exercise} Mostre que \begin{enumerate}[(a)] \item 
 $\frac{\text{sen} \theta + \text{sen}{(2\theta)}}{1+\cos \theta +
 \cos{(2\theta)}} = \tan \theta$ se $0 \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$
 \item  Se $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, para qual(is) valor(es) de
 $\theta$ a identidade na questão a) não é verdadeira?  
 \end{enumerate} \end{exercise}


 
 % Question 3 \begin{exercise}\textit{College Trigonometry, Aufmann:}
 Prove a identidade $$\frac{\text{tg} x}{1-\cot x}+\frac{\cot
 x}{1-\text{tg} x}=\sec x \text{cosec} x + 1$$

 
\end{exercise}
 
 \begin{exercise} Mostre que $\frac{\text{sen} x +
 \text{sen}{(3x)}+\text{sen}{(5x)}}{\cos x +
 \cos{(3x)}+\cos{(5x)}}=\text{tg}{3x}$ para todo $x$ para o qual
 $\text{tg}{(3x)}$ é definida.

 
 \end{exercise}
 
 \begin{exercise} Se $f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$ para
 todo $x\neq 0,1,$ e $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, então encontre
 $f(\sec^2\theta)$. \end{exercise}
 
 \begin{exercise} \textit{New York State Mathematics League:} Encontre
 $A$ tal que $0^\circ < A < 90^\circ$ e $\cos 41^\circ + \sin 41^\circ
= \sqrt2 \sin A$. \end{exercise}
 



 \end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to do something similar to the model shown in this photo (but at the same time remove this "1" after "Jee Advanced").

How do I place the question sources next to the "Problema" and its numbering?

Comment: Please, don't add code as a quote. Paste the code and add three backquotes at the beginning and three backquotes at the end, or select the code and click on the `{}` icon above the text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=0.75in,rmargin=0.75in,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\everymath{\displaystyle} % ------------------- % Packages %------------------- 
\usepackage{    
 amsmath,            % Math Environments     
 amssymb,            % Extended Symbols  
 enumerate,          % Enumerate Environments   
 graphicx,           % Include Images    
 lastpage,           % Reference Lastpage   
 multicol,           % Use Multi-columns     
 multirow            % Use Multi-rows
 } 
 \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 
 \usepackage{tikz, tabularx}
 \usepackage{graphics}
 %\newcolumntype{W}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%Para agilizar las columnas. % ------------------- % Font % -------------------
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
 \usepackage{charter}

 % ------------------- % Commands % -------------------
 \newcommand{\homework}[2]{\noindent\textbf{Nombre completo:}\makebox[3in]{\hrulefill} \hfill \textbf{IQ 0312} \\  \textbf{Fecha de entrega: #2} \hfill \textbf{Simulacro #1}\\}
 
 \newcommand{\pointproblem}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{problema}%     
    \noindent \textbf{Problema \theproblem.} (#1 points)\,% 
 } 
 \newcommand{\pspace}{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}}
 \newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

% ------------------- % Theorem Environment % -------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{exercise}{Problema}%
    {enhanced,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable, 
    after skip=16pt,
    toptitle=4pt,
    bottomtitle=4pt,
    left=6pt,
    right=6pt,
    boxrule=1pt,
    titlerule=.5pt,
    rounded corners,
    arc=6pt,
    opacityback=0,
    colbacktitle=white,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    separator sign={~-},
    }{ex}

 
 % ------------------- % Header & Footer % -------------------
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 
 \fancypagestyle{pages}{    %Headers    
 \fancyhead[L]{}     \fancyhead[C]{}
    \fancyhead[R]{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %Footers
    \fancyfoot[L]{}     \fancyfoot[C]{}     \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage \,de
 \pageref{LastPage}} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt} }
 \headheight=0pt \footskip=14pt
 
 \pagestyle{pages}
 
 % ------------------- % Content % ------------------- 
 \begin{document}
\homework{\#}{MM/DD}

 
 % Question 1 
\begin{exercise}{JEE (Advanced)}{} 
Mostre que
$$\frac{\cot x-1}{\cot x+1}=\frac{\cos{(2x)}}{1+\sin{(2x)}}$$  
\end{exercise}

% Question 2 
\begin{exercise}{}{} 
Mostre que \begin{enumerate}[(a)] \item 
 $\frac{\text{sen} \theta + \text{sen}{(2\theta)}}{1+\cos \theta +
 \cos{(2\theta)}} = \tan \theta$ se $0 \leq \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$
 \item  Se $\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$, para qual(is) valor(es) de
 $\theta$ a identidade na questão a) não é verdadeira?  
\end{enumerate} 
\end{exercise}

% Question 3 
\begin{exercise}{College Trigonometry, Aufmann}{}
Prove a identidade $$\frac{\text{tg} x}{1-\cot x}+\frac{\cot
 x}{1-\text{tg} x}=\sec x \text{cosec} x + 1$$
\end{exercise}
 
\begin{exercise}{}{} 
Mostre que $\frac{\text{sen} x +
 \text{sen}{(3x)}+\text{sen}{(5x)}}{\cos x +
 \cos{(3x)}+\cos{(5x)}}=\text{tg}{3x}$ para todo $x$ para o qual
 $\text{tg}{(3x)}$ é definida.
\end{exercise}
 
\begin{exercise}{}{} 
Se $f\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}$ para
 todo $x\neq 0,1,$ e $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, então encontre
 $f(\sec^2\theta)$. 
 \end{exercise}
 
\begin{exercise}{New York State Mathematics League}{} 
Encontre
 $A$ tal que $0^\circ < A < 90^\circ$ e $\cos 41^\circ + \sin 41^\circ
= \sqrt2 \sin A$. 
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]